# Addition of AC Voltage Polar Form

Tags: voltage

Question 5 Part A Only. I tried converting polar form to rectangular form to add the AC voltage sources and converting it back to polar form. I got the angle **(10.09 degree)** right but not the r-value and I still can't seem to find my mistake.
(I use my calculator for polar to rectangular form conversion vise versa)

My working is on this link:
https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/track?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:51d470e1-906c-42f2-8a7c-aae15008c33d

Answer (5a): **23.568∠10.09 degrees**

[image: Question]

Comment: Please type in your work instead of linking to it or, at a minimum, include an image of your work in your post. All information needs to be in your post rather than linked somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just fell (slightly) at the final hurdle: -

[image]

You correctly arrived at 33.33 volts but that is peak voltage. The RMS is 23.568 volts i.e. \$\sqrt2\$ lower.

[image]